# QGIS 3.32 - Composer - display pdf image and export as vector

Tags: qgis, print-composer, html

I need to display a complex vector image in the composer. QGIS doesn't display svg files correctly that way, is there a way to import a pdf via html, and export it as a "true" vector image, from the composer ?

Answer (score 0):

without testing...perhaps

georeference  the image (see 14.2.2. basic Follow Along: Georeferencing the scanned map here: [enter link description here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/fr/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.%20html)) (cf capt 1)

then polygonize the raster (cf capt 2)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but that's really not working with this kind of non-spatial vector "artwork". And obviously I need to keep the aspects as defined in Inkscape, so it's better no transform it to raster then vector.

It was promising though !